# Can using an SVG from <object> allow click events to propagate to parent handlers?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Adding an SVG from an HTML `<object>` appears to create an unresponsive space where click events are not propagated through the SVG and object elements.

In the example, this is demonstrated by clicking in the center of the button. The click action doesn't appear to propagate the event to the parent element, the button. However, when the edge of the button is clicked (away from the SVG), the click event is invoked.

```js
var buttonEl = document.getElementById('button');
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Clicked!')
})
```

```html
<button id="button" style="padding:5rem;">
  <object data="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/check.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="height:40px;width:40px;">
    Check
  </object>
</button>
```

Comment: I am supposing this is caused by the capturing and bubbling phases stopping the event propagation at the object element's inner document root, which is the SVG element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `pointer-events:none;` on the object element.

```js
var buttonEl = document.getElementById('button');
buttonEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Clicked!')
})
```

```html
<button id="button" style="padding:5rem;">
  <object style="pointer-events:none;height:40px;width:40px;" data="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/check.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    Check
  </object>
</button>
```

Comment: dear anonymous, you saved me from the hanging rope

Answer (score 1):

@brettinternet's answer won't help if you have hover styles or other such interactivity that you need to maintain inside the SVG. I figured out that the proper way to handle this is to attach your click listeners to the `contentDocument` of the `<object>` element but you have to wait until the external document is loaded before doing this.

```
let yourObject = document.querySelector('object#objid');
yourObject.addEventListener('load', event => { 
    yourObject.contentDocument.addEventListener('click', event => 
        console.log(event));
    });
});
```